# How to create files corresponding to program location?

Tags: c++, windows, file

Is there a way to create files on a computer using C++ and the location of the C++ program? I want to be able to use this program on multiple computers yet each computer has its own different directory. For example if I want to create test.txt file located on the user directory is there a way to put the path of the file corresponding to the program file's location because "user" differs on the name of the user.

Comment: Use the `GetModuleFileName` function.

Comment: ... but depending on the scenario it would probably be better to look up the location of the user's Documents folder (or perhaps the application data folder) - see [Known Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911(v=vs.85).aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score -1):

as long as you are on windows you can use the API GetUserName then use SetCurrentDirectory API to change working directory then create your file there using CreateFile or fstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    ULONG len = 50;
    LPSTR lpBuffer = (LPSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, len);
    GetUserName(lpBuffer, &len);
    cout << lpBuffer << endl;
    // don't forget to clean when you're done:

    string str = "C:\\Users\\";
    str += lpBuffer;
    str += "\\test.txt";
    cout << str << endl;

    ofstream out(str.c_str());
    if(out.fail())
        perror("Opening failed");
    out << "Hello " << lpBuffer;

    out.close();

    GlobalFree(lpBuffer);


    GlobalFree(lpBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

this program gets the current username and creates file inside its folder and writes in it "Hello" 'yourusername'

Comment: There's no guarantee that the user's profile will always be C:\Users\<username> and in fact there are a number of cases where it won't be.  Besides, the profile is the wrong place to put files.

Comment: There are multiple issues with this answer: `1` Using `GlobalAlloc` for a buffer, that could just as well be stack-allocated; `2` Making absolutely sure, that the code fails with certain Unicode characters in the user name; `3` Constructing a path that may or may not exist; `4` Using `std::basic_ios::fail()` the wrong way; `5` Calling `GlobalFree` twice on `lpBuffer`.